# problems with jar file in netbeans ide

Tags: netbeans, jar

I have done rfid reader program in netbeans ide, works fine. then,I created executable jar file by following the steps.
In the netbeans main window,

(i)select the properties under the project folder under properties > build >packaging then enter OK.

(ii)Select Run tab in main window then clean and build Main project.
After these steps, the executable jar file is created in documents> netbeansprojects>project name folder>dist.

I run the jar file from command prompt by 
`java -jar C:\Users\Holoteq-PC01\Desktop\RFID1\RFIDreader.jar` 
then i got the error as 
`Error: could not open C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\i386\jvm.cfg`

why the error comes like that?

i checked java location by `where java` then the response is

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe
```

I read multiple questions pertaining to this issue,i tried almost but the error persists. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.